# Injections in guice don't work everywhere

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to inject some service by Google Guice @Inject annotation:

```
 @Inject
 Service service;
```

This inject is working but not in all places. When it doesn't work i catch null pointer. What can be a problem  ? Obviously, all attemps were within single project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[If you do not create your instances with `.getInstance()` nothing will be injected. The annotation is not magic.](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#injections)

[You have to use `requestStaticInjection()` on `static` references that are annotated with `@Inject`.](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections)

[This is all explained in extreme detail in the Guice documentation.](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections)